# Trying to show sub-menu on click and hide on click if already shown. Also remove show class on if clicked on a new item

Tags: javascript

I have a nav menu with list items and sub-menus under each.  I am trying to make the submenu visible on click of parent and hide when clicked again or on another item in main menu.  I have everything working except for hiding the submenu when clicking the parent a second time.

My question would be what am I doing wrong for the second click on parent not working to hide the submenu.  I have tried replacing my if statement with a simple toggle class which gives the same result.

UPDATE:  I now have the updated code below working to hide when clicking the parent item again.  However I have lost the submenu hiding when clicking a different menu item.

```
- - UPDATED - -
let dropDowns = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#menu-menu li.menu-item-has-children'));

    const handleClick = (e) => { 
      if (e.currentTarget.querySelector('ul.sub-menu').classList.contains('show')) {        
          e.currentTarget.querySelector('ul.sub-menu').classList.remove('show');
          e.currentTarget.classList.remove('nav-active');
      }else {                
          e.currentTarget.querySelector('ul.sub-menu').classList.add('show');
          e.currentTarget.classList.add('nav-active');
      }      
    }

    dropDowns.forEach(node => {
    node.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
    }); 


- - ORIGINAL - - 
let dropDowns = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#menu-menu li.menu-item-has-children'));

    const handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    dropDowns.forEach(node => {
        node.querySelector('ul.sub-menu').classList.remove('show');
    });
    
    
    if (e.currentTarget.querySelector('ul.sub-menu').classList.contains('show')) {
        console.log('click-with-show')
        e.currentTarget.querySelector('ul.sub-menu').classList.remove('show');
    }else {
        console.log('click-no-show')
        e.currentTarget.querySelector('ul.sub-menu').classList.add('show');
    }  
    
    }

    dropDowns.forEach(node => {
    node.addEventListener('click', handleClick)
    });
```

```
<ul id="menu-menu">
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">Parent Item
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">Parent Item
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">Parent Item
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="menu-item-has-children">Parent Item
    <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
        <li>Sub Menu Item</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Could you also provide your HTML steucture of the dropdowns?

Comment: Added HTML structure

Comment: First of all `dropDowns.forEach(node => { node.querySelector('ul.sub-menu').classList.remove('show'); });` you don't need to remove each dropdown's `show` class before deciding whether or not to add `show` class. You can delete that statement. Without it, the code should work as it is. Can you try?

Comment: oddly, deleting that line kept the submenus from showing at all.

Comment: I have it working without that line now, however I have lost the submenu closing when a different parent is clicked now.  Any thoughts? @M.ÇağlarTUFAN  Thanks!